# Web Access Logs using RHadoop

Tags: rhadoop

Can anyone point me in the direction of an example of the data mining of web access logs using RHadoop? I've been reading 'Big Data Analysis with R and Hadoop' and certain aspects are confusing. It's the final year and few weeks of my studies and time is a factor. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tommy